# Open a binary file in c

Tags: c, file, io, embedded, fopen

I am trying to save some binary data in a file (5 vectors of 8 bits) in c. This is the code I have made for that:

```
  FILE* flatencies;
  flatencies=fopen("savelatencies.bin", "wb+");
  if(flatencies == NULL){
      perror("\n Error!: ");
  }
  while(1){
  *p_gpio_capture = 0x0 ;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++){
          fwrite(*(latency+i), 8, 1, flatencies);
      }
  }
  fclose(flatencies);
```

I am executing this script in an embedded system. But I get this message from perror in the serial terminal: "Error!: : I/O error". I don't understand very well the error and I don't know how to solve it. If anyone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: hmmm `perror()` is being obtuse... maybe your disk is full? you don't have write permissions for the working directory?

Comment: Unrelated: `*(latency + i)` is usually written as `latency[i]`. You probably want either `latency + i` or `&latency[i]`. BTW: your loop can be compacted to one statement: `fwrite(*(latency+0), 8, 5, flatencies);`

Comment: Unrelated: I suppose it's my problem for having my mind in the gutter, but I would choose a different name for `flatencies`, perhaps just `f_latencies`. :-)

Comment: You say “5 vectors of 8 bits” but your code tries to write 8 _bytes_ (of 8 bits each).  Is that a typo or part of the problem?

Comment: As minimum information you should include all variable definitions into your sample code. Type and initialization do matter.

Comment: Well first of all does your "embedded system" even have a filesystem? And have you initialised it (such as mounted the media)?  "Embedded system" does not define the platform, which is critical to this question.  And you might get out of the habit of referring to C source as "script".  It is not that.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

1. You are continuing to write to the file even if opening it fails.

```c
if(flatencies == NULL) {
    perror("\n Error!: ");
    // You should return here
}
...
```

2. You don't seem to break from the `while` loop. This will cause your program to loop forever. You should consider breaking from it at some point. (Actually, it seems useless to me so I don't see why you wrote it in the first place).

---

As for the error, you should print the value of `errno` and see your platform-specific documentation to know what it actually means.

Comment: "As for the error..." that's what [`perror()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) is, **portably**, for. Looking at an implementation specific error codes (IBM's z/VSE 6.2.0 in your link) is no help if the user implemenattion has different ones.

Comment: @pmg I know, but it should give the OP some clues about why this error is happening. I have edited the post anyway.

Comment: It takes more work to print the error code and look it up than to use `perror()` in the first place :)

Comment: I doubt it, all your "clues" refer to code executed after the error mentioned in the question has occurred.  They may be valid _comments_ on the code, but not an answer, or even a "clue".